# Is there a better/safe way to cast non-const reference of shared_ptr to a base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, shared-ptr

If you have a class Base with virtual methods and a class Implementation which implements the virtual methods, is there any way to cast std::shared_ptr < Implementation > & to std::shared < Base > &? The compiler allows this for const references, but for non const references it fails as in "Case A" in the code below. Is there an easy way to do this?

If not, how safe is my workaround "questionable_cast" in Case B?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void set_value(int x) = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Base
{
public:
    Implementation() : m_value(0) { }
    void set_value(int x) override
    {
    m_value = x;
    }
    int get_value() const
    {
    return m_value;
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};


void do_something(std::shared_ptr<Base>& base)
{
    base->set_value(5);

    /// Code like this makes the non-const argument necessary
    base = std::make_shared<Implementation>();
}

template <class T, class U>
std::shared_ptr<T>& questionable_cast(std::shared_ptr<U>& u)
{
    /// This code is here to assure the cast is allowed
    std::shared_ptr<T> tmp = u;
    (void)tmp;

    return *reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>*>(&u);
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> a = std::make_shared<Implementation>();

    // The following line causes a compiler error:
    //  invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<Base>&’ ...
    // do_something(a);
    // do_something(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(a));

    // This is the workaround
    do_something(questionable_cast<Base>(a));

    std::cerr << "a = " << a->get_value() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bonus question: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a reference instead of just making a copy like you do in the `questionable_cast` function? Using a reference won't increment the counter and makes it possible for the reference to be invalidated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but possible reasons: *Why* do you want to do this?  Using reinterpret_cast like this is bound to be a violation of the strict aliasing rules, and hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: I updated the code so that you can see why the argument needs to be non-const reference. And believe me, I don't want to use reinterpret_cast. That's why I'm asking if there is a way around it

Comment: There must be several answers to why `Derived*&` (or `Derived**`) is not convertible to `Base*&`(or `Base**`), and this is the same issue. In short: it's not type-safe. (Consider the case of passing a pointer to a different derived class to `do_something`.)

Comment: So "a" may end up pointing to a different Implementation than "Implementation" in main. Yeah.. that's a deal breaker. Thanks. I think that is really the answer to this question: Don't do it because of that.

Answer (score 2):

Two obvious solutions to the problem as originally asked:  1.  Make `do_something` take a const reference to a shared_ptr (or a shared_ptr by value).  2.  Create a named shared_ptr and pass a reference to that: Eg

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> a = std::make_shared<Implementation>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> b = a;  // This conversion works.
    do_something(b);  // Pass a reference to b instead.
    return 0;
}
```

Your `questionable_cast` function is a violation of the strict aliasing rules, and invokes undefined behaviour.  It's quite likely to work in initial tests, and then a new release of the compiler will crank up the optimization a notch, and it will fail during a demo.

To handle the case where `do_something` changes the pointer:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> a = std::make_shared<Implementation>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> b = a;  // This conversion works.
    do_something(b);  // Pass a reference to b instead.
    const auto aa = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Implementation>(b);
    if (aa)
        a = aa;
    else
        ; // Handle the error here
    return 0;
}
```

If `do_something` guarantees to return a pointer of the same derived type, even if it doesn't return the same pointer, wrap it in a template function:

```
template <typename T>
void do_something_ex( std::shared_ptr<T>& a )
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> b = a;
    do_something(b)
    a = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(b);
    if (!a)
        throw_or_assert;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I forgot an important feature of what the do_something. It may also change the shared_ptr. So then neither of your suggestions would work.

Comment: @bofjas: It still can, and such changes will be reflected in `b`. If you want them reflected into `a`, then copy `b` back into it.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I didn't want to do that is because then I need to do a dynamic_pointer_cast and check the result so there will be a lot of code every place I call the function, but I didn't realize that was actually telling me what was unsafe with my approach. Guess I'm stuck with that solution. Thanks for the help though!